# Rails Tests Fail With Sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I seem to be getting a strange error when I run my tests in rails, they are all failing for the same reason and none of the online documentation seems particularly helpful in regards to this particular error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

This error is crippling my ability to test my application and seems to have appeared suddenly.  I have the latest version of sqlite3 (3.6.2), the latest sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4) gem and the latest rails (2.1.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/4403 which shows a workaround. Could that be the problem you are encountering?

Comment: just as a note : the "in-memory" fix is also available as a plugin 
http://nubyonrails.com/articles/2006/06/01/san-francisco-sqlite3-memory-tests-asteroids
and
http://github.com/rsl/memory_test_fix/tree/master

Comment: Link is dead. Here's the [lastest from the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100715165532/dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/4403)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once but with MySQL.  Turned out I hadn't created the test database. Doh!  Rails and sqlite creates them automatically I believe (at least it does in windows).

Are trying to do in memory testing?  If not does the test database exist?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I actually ended up just deleting the rails folder and checking back out the last working copy from version control.  I've made the identical changes and this problem hasn't reappeared, so either I messed up or rails had some sort of hiccup.  Thankfully I had version control :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running a test with the last statement being a click on a form submit.  Once I did an assertion or should test, the test closed properly, and I didn't have to rerun the rake db:test:prepare