# SQLite3 Error - cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

## SOLVED (see below)

When I'm trying to create or destroy a record (running on SQLite3) in my Ruby on Rails app (or in console as well) I'm getting an SQL Exception:

```
irb(main):014:0> ApiCache.all
=> []
irb(main):015:0> ApiCache.create(:hash => 'qwe', :contents => 'asd')
SQLite3::SQLException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite
3/database.rb:97:in `close'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite
3/database.rb:97:in `prepare'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite
3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite
3/database.rb:517:in `rollback'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:168:in `rollback_db_transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:176:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record
/base.rb:498:in `create'
        from (irb):15
        from :0
irb(main):016:0> ApiCache.all
=> [#<ApiCache id: 9, hash: "qwe", contents: "asd", created_at: "2011-05-09 13:09:31", updated_at: "
2011-05-09 13:09:31">]
```

The record saves into the database but also throws this kind of error. I tried to delete my DB then create and migrate it again, but it doesn't appear to make any good.

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to fix it. I've never faced such thing before =(

## SOLUTION

I've destroyed my model and created another one. Must be some conflict in attribute names, as the new one now has **fp:string contents:text** and works nicely. Might be the word **hash** that ruined SQLite =) Thank y'all!

Comment: Please grant the answer flag to one of the answers.

Answer (score 9):

Holy smokes... The situation is in-fact that the field name "hash" causes sqlite3 to throw this very unhelpful error.  Tricky one...

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to never to make an instance method named "hash". This is used by a ton of ruby objects for comparison and equality. No matter weather your using SQLite, or anything, a custom hash method should only be done when you know what you want from it's results. In this case ActiveRecord made the method for you. I would rename the column :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to look here: [Rails Tests Fail With Sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116887/rails-tests-fail-with-sqlite3) Looks like they may have found a workaround.

Comment: The links in that thread are all 404's =( I've already looked through the web but didn't find anything relevant...