# How to generate a unique object hash based on the class attributes?

Tags: ruby, hash, sqlite, uniqueidentifier

I have a model with different attributes. Not every instance has a value for each attribute.

```
class Location

  attr_accessible :name,     # string, default => :null
                  :size,     # integer, default => 0
                  :latitude, # float, default => 0
                  :longitude # float, default => 0

  # Returns a unique hash for the instance.
  def hash
   # ...
  end

end
```

How can I implement a hash function which returns a unique id for an instance? It should be the same every time I invoke the hash function on the object. I do not want a random unique id. It should be possible to store the hash in a sqlite3 database without modification.

---

As you can read in an [answer by MetaSkills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610555/356895) it is **not a good idea to overwrite** the `hash` method since it *"is used by a ton of ruby objects for comparison and equality"*. I will therefore rename it to `custom_attributes_hash`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require 'digest/md5'

class Location

  attr_accessor :name,     # string, default => :null
                  :size,     # integer, default => 0
                  :latitude, # float, default => 0
                  :longitude # float, default => 0

  # Returns a unique hash for the instance.
  def hash
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(self))
  end

end
```

test with pry

```
[1] pry(main)> foo = Location.new;
[2] pry(main)> foo.name = 'foo';
[3] pry(main)> foo.size = 1;
[4] pry(main)> foo.latitude = 12345;
[5] pry(main)> foo.longitude = 54321;
[6] pry(main)> 
[7] pry(main)> foo.hash
=> "2044fd3756152f629fb92707cb9441ba"
[8] pry(main)> 
[9] pry(main)> foo.size = 2
=> 2
[10] pry(main)> foo.hash
=> "c600666b44eebe72510cc5133d8b4afb"
```

Or you could also create your customize function for serializing the properties. for example to use all of the instance variable

```
def hash
  variables = instance_variables.map {|ivar| instance_variable_get(ivar)}.join("|separator|")
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(variables)
end
```

or to select the one you need

```
def hash
  variables = [name, size].join("|separator|")
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(variables)
end
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way I can define which attributes are involved to build the hash?